# flask python creating swagger document error

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, swagger, flask-restful

I am trying to generate a swagger documentation for the API I am building in flask however when I execute below code I get very staring error, What I am missing here ?

This is what I have tried :

```
try:
    from flask import Flask, g, request
    from flask_restful import Resource, Api
    from flask_limiter.util import get_remote_address
    from flask_limiter import Limiter
    from flasgger import Swagger
    from flasgger.utils import swag_from
    from flask_restful_swagger import swagger
    from flask_httpauth import HTTPTokenAuth
    import os
    import json
except Exception as e:
    print("some modules are missing {}".format(e))  

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
limiter = Limiter(app, key_func=get_remote_address)
limiter.init_app(app)
api = swagger.docs(Api(app), apiVersion='0.1', api_spec_url='/doc')

auth = HTTPTokenAuth(scheme='Token')

tokens = {
    'awserftggyjkk34)ghtyrjrhhye34nnmw': 'cadmin',
    'bwsosjhee(dhj345gtyuioplsertbsjkl': 'dadmin',
    'mnchthas(sjklertyusvfgmbshdls234h': 'eadmin'

}
@auth.verify_token
def verify_token(token):
   if token in tokens:
       g.current_user = tokens[token]
       return True
   return False

class defr(Resource):

    decorators = [limiter.limit("100/day")]
    @swagger.model
    @swagger.operation(notes='my notes ntes')
    @auth.login_required
    def currentuser(self):
        return "Hello, %s!" % g.current_user


api.add_resource(defr, '/user')
```

error :

```
  File "C:\Users\codamd\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask_restful_swagger\swagger.py", line 294, in extract_operations
    for method in [m.lower() for m in resource.methods]:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Any help would be great

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you've used a custom named method in your `defr` class. The [Flask-RESTful documentation](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#resourceful-routing) specifies defining HTTP methods in your `Resource` class e.g.

```
class defr(Resource):

    decorators = [limiter.limit("100/day")]
    @swagger.model
    @swagger.operation(notes='my notes ntes')
    @auth.login_required
    def get(self):
        return "Hello, %s!" % g.current_user
```

Comment: NOw I get below error after changing to HTTP method as `get` 
`TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type`

Comment: Can you show the complete stack trace for this error as I ran your code and I did not face any errors like this..

Comment: This is the new error : `AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'cli'`

Comment: Also how can I pass the authorization token here ?

Comment: for the first error, installation of `click` or `flask-cli` might've been errorneous depending on the version oi Flask you're using. Check this [page](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/cli/) of Flask's documentation

Comment: As for the authorization token, you can pass it using the `Authorization` Header e.g. `Authorization Token <token-value>`

Comment: Thanks , Yup but for authorization how in swagger I can pass, so if you see in my code `localhost:5000/doc.html` is my swagger ui there how can I pass the Authorization

Comment: I don't think `flask-rest-swagger` provides that functionality as far as I know. The only relevant documentation I could find regarding this is [this issue](https://github.com/rantav/flask-restful-swagger/issues/100) and [this one](https://github.com/rantav/flask-restful-swagger/issues/73). However I would recommend using a REST client like Postman to access your APIs as swagger is just a specification document

Comment: Agreed but Swagger is more that documentation :-) Why not use that as rest client as well along with documentation